# Configuring electron-forge v6 for typescript, react v18, and tailwindcss v3

Tags: reactjs, typescript, electron, tailwind-css, electron-forge

I'm trying to setup an electron app using electron-forge and the latest versions of react v18 and tailwindcss v3. I followed instructions for getting ef configured for typescript and react here: https://www.electronforge.io/guides/framework-integration/react-with-typescript

I then followed instructions for configuring tailwindcss + electron here: https://www.debugandrelease.com/how-to-use-tailwindcss-with-electron/

And this all seems to have worked - my debug environment starts up properly when I run `npm run start`. However, the environment continuously refreshes. It seems that something is rebuilding / refreshing in the background, causing webpack to recompile the typescript, resulting in the webpack-dev-server causing a hot reload. Anyone have tips on where to go from here?

Answer (score 0):

Default Electron Forge integration with webpack & react is very bare bones. We've also been stuck with a similar situation in past when the hot reload couldn't work properly.

Ended up using this github repository to have decent pre-configured environment ready to built upon:
https://github.com/codesbiome/electron-react-webpack-typescript-2023